# Rails Routes: How to match Rails routes based on a pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some routes like:

```
get 'route1'  => 'controller#route1', as: 'route1'
get 'route2'  => 'controller#route2', as: 'route2'
get 'route3'  => 'controller#route3', as: 'route3'
```

How can I match more routes automatically with this pattern, e.g. 4, 5...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you can handle `as` part of route. But you can write this code in another way. You can create a route that handle all such routes at the end of your primary route as below:

```
get '/:route'  => 'controller#route_for_all_views'
```

In your controller you should have this `route_for_all_views` action, which can handle all pages.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def route_for_all_views
    # handle your views and code with params[:route] here
  end
end
```

Comment: you had noticed me, i do it like this:  `get '/:routes', to: 'controller#route_for_all_views'`, constraints: { routes: /^routes\d$/ }`, and controller is like yours, very thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this:

```
get "/:action", to: "controller", constraints: {action: /route\d+/}
```

Please see [dynamic segments](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#dynamic-segments) for routes.

(also note that this would raise an exception if your controller doesn't have the method so you might need to use something like `method_missing`)

Answer (score 0):

This may be a messy solution, but you could also do something like this, which will give you the `*_path` and `*_url` url helpers, that you get when you use the `:as` option.

```
%w{ route1 route2 route3 route4 route5 }.each do |route|
  get route, to: "controller##{route}", as: route
end
```